# select single image on click <img> tag

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I have rendered multiple images using  tag. I want to change the background color of image when it is clicked. But when I click on one image, the color of all the images changed.

Here is my code.
I am working in Angular.

**html**

```
<img
 [src]="data.Url" alt="image"
 (click)="_upload(data.Url)" 
 [ngClass]="{'green' : toggle, 'red': !toggle}"
>
```

**ts**

inside my function

```
this.toggle = !this.toggle;
this.status = this.toggle ? 'Enable' : 'Disable';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rendering multiple html elements, I assume you are using the `ngFor` directive, so you could use the `index` for giving each element a different `css` class.

For example:

**HTML**

```html
<div *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index">
 <img
   [src]="option.Url"
   (click)="_upload(option.Url, i)"
   [class.selected]="i === indexSelected" <!--apply the selected css class if condition is TRUE-->
  >
</div>
```

**css**

```css
.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

**ts**

```js
...
export class YourComponent {
  indexSelected: number = -1;

  _upload(url: string, index: number) {
    // ...
    this.indexSelected = index;
  }
}
```

Comment: this answer was helpful. thanks @Andres2142

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all I did this in this way

```
<td *ngFor="let data of responseData; let i= index;" (click)="active= i" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': active === i ? '#4b8df2' : 'white' }">
    <div>
    <img 
     [src]="data.Url" alt="image"
     (click)="_upload(data.Url)" 
    >
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).